# Video not playing but audio plays fine on Live Streaming in android

Tags: android, audio, video, rtmp, http-live-streaming

I have a `VideoView` which is used to play live stream. I am not able to find where the problem occurs.

In the beginning, I used **RTMP** to play the live stream using **Vitamio** which resulted in playing the audio leaving the screen blank. I checked out with the RTMP link, it works fine with a website. I surfed a lot about this, but I did not find any solution.

So now, I switched to **HTTP** to play the live stream which also results in the same problem (i.e audio playing fine but video is blank).

I am expecting a solution for either **RTMP** or **HTTP**.

Any Suggestions???

**UPDATE 1:** I have found a problem with the link. I used VLC Media Player to check whether my RTMP and HTTP link is working fine or not.  The **RTMP** link works fine whereas the problem was with the ***HTTP*** link. The HTTP link plays only the audio.

On the other hand, having the RTMP link working fine, it doesn't solve the problem when using **Vitamio**. Any Suggestions for RTMP??

Here is my code:

```
public class ITVLiveStreamActivity extends Activity {

private VideoView liveVideoView;

     @Override
     protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
         super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
         setContentView(R.layout.activity_itvlive_stream);

         liveVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.liveVideoView);

         MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
         mediaController.setAnchorView(liveVideoView);
         Uri uri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("rtmp://61.16.143.170:1935/live/7khh-8fhu-vxd3-8fuw"));
         liveVideoView.setVideoURI(uri);
         liveVideoView.setMediaController(mediaController);
         liveVideoView.requestFocus();
         liveVideoView.start();

     }
}
```

**UPDATE 2:**

Here is my code using **Vitamio**:

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;

import io.vov.vitamio.LibsChecker;
import io.vov.vitamio.MediaPlayer;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.MediaController;
import io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView;

public class ITVLiveStreamActivity extends Activity {

    private String pathToFileOrUrl="rtmp://61.16.143.170:1935/live/7khh-8fhu-vxd3-8fuw";
    private VideoView mVideoView;
    private ProgressDialog progDailog;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        if(!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
            return;
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_itvlive_stream);

        mVideoView = (VideoView)findViewById(R.id.vitamio_videoView);

        progDailog = new ProgressDialog(this);
        progDailog.setCancelable(false);
        progDailog.setMessage(getResources().getString(R.string.loading));
        progDailog.show();

        mVideoView.setVideoPath(pathToFileOrUrl);
        mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
        mVideoView.requestFocus();

        mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                progDailog.dismiss();
                mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I am getting the same result (i.e) Audio is playing but video is blank.

Here I have added the screenshot

[image: screenshot]

Comment: which server you are using ? wowza for streaming ?

Comment: @Saveen yes, I am using Wowza.

Comment: so nothing is depends on your playing library.Once please check your created url is working fine or not.You can check in vlc using streams

Comment: @Saveen, I checked out with VLC. My url is working fine.

Comment: is  stream working fine ? both audio and video ?

Comment: did you try with this ? startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
     Uri.parse("pass your stream url")));

Answer (score 1):

### You can create an activity like this to open default Video View

```
public class VideoViewActivity extends Activity {

    // Declare variables
    ProgressDialog pDialog;
    VideoView videoview;

    // Insert your Video URL
//      String VideoURL; /*= "http://www.androidbegin.com/tutorial/AndroidCommercial.3gp";*/
    String VideoURL;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Get the layout from video_main.xml
        setContentView(R.layout.video_view);
        // Find your VideoView in your video_main.xml layout
        videoview = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.VideoView);
        // Execute StreamVideo AsyncTask
        VideoURL = getIntent().getExtras().getString(Constants.LINK);
//        Log.v("video", VideoURL);
        // Create a progressbar
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(VideoViewActivity.this);
        // Set progressbar title
        //pDialog.setTitle("Android Video Streaming Tutorial");
        // Set progressbar message
        pDialog.setMessage("Buffering...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        // Show progressbar
        pDialog.show();

        try {
            // Start the MediaController
            MediaController mediacontroller = new MediaController(
                    VideoViewActivity.this);
            mediacontroller.setAnchorView(videoview);
            // Get the URL from String VideoURL
            Uri video = Uri.parse(VideoURL);
            videoview.setMediaController(mediacontroller);
            videoview.setVideoURI(video);

        } catch (Exception e) {
//            Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
            pDialog.dismiss();
            e.printStackTrace();

        } finally {
            videoview.setOnErrorListener(new OnErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onError(MediaPlayer mp, int what, int extra) {
                    CommonUtilities.showToast(VideoViewActivity.this, "Video Format not supported by device.");
                    VideoViewActivity.this.finish();
                    return true;
                }
            });
        }

        videoview.requestFocus();
        videoview.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {
            // Close the progress bar and play the video
            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                pDialog.dismiss();
                videoview.start();
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Comment: ya sure, I will try your code. Now the problem is in the HTTP link. I will notify as soon as I solve the HTTP link problem. On the other hand, I would also like to hear a suggestion for the **RTMP** link using **Vitamio**.

Comment: I tried your code bro, I got the Toast message "Video Format not supported by device." Can you figure out what the problem is?

Comment: yes there are few formats that are by default supported by videoview like 3gp, low quality mp4 etc

Comment: Is it possible to use an RTMP link as VideoURL?

Comment: i haven't tried it yet. Please give it a try and let me know. Thanks

Comment: I tried with RTMP link, which in turn is also displaying the same Toast message. I also tried without the `errorListener`, and for this, it shows "Can't play this video". Any Suggestions?

Comment: i am busy right now but will surely look forward on this. Thanks

Comment: ya fine, go ahead with your work. I will continue working on it. If I find any solution I will update here.

Comment: your welcome. Don't forget to update if u find a solution :).

Answer (score 1):

hi i have done this and its working fine here is code

```
public class PlayingLiveStream extends Activity {

VideoView vvmyliveplaying;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_playinglivestream);
    vvmyliveplaying = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.vvmyliveplaying);
    MediaController mediaController = new MediaController(this);
    mediaController.setAnchorView(vvmyliveplaying);
    Uri uri = Uri.parse(getIntent().getStringExtra("url_play"));
    vvmyliveplaying.setVideoURI(uri);
    vvmyliveplaying.setMediaController(mediaController);
    vvmyliveplaying.requestFocus();

}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
        try {
            vvmyliveplaying.pause();
            finish();
        } catch (Exception e) {

        }
    }
    return false;

}
}
```

```
<VideoView
    android:id="@+id/vvmyliveplaying"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

**Edited Answer**

I have tested streaming on vitamio library demo sample and its working fine.

public class VideoViewDemo extends Activity {

```
private VideoView mVideoView;
private String pathToFileOrUrl ="rtmp://61.16.143.170:1935/live/7khh-8fhu-vxd3-8fuw";
private ProgressDialog progDailog;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle icicle) {
    super.onCreate(icicle);
    if (!LibsChecker.checkVitamioLibs(this))
        return;
    setContentView(R.layout.videoview);

    mVideoView = (VideoView) findViewById(R.id.surface_view);


    progDailog = new ProgressDialog(this);
    progDailog.setCancelable(false);
    progDailog.setMessage("Please wait");
    progDailog.show();

    mVideoView.setVideoPath(pathToFileOrUrl);
    mVideoView.setMediaController(new MediaController(this));
    mVideoView.requestFocus();

    mVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
            progDailog.dismiss();
            mediaPlayer.setPlaybackSpeed(1.0f);
        }
    });
}

}
```

and xml layout,

```
<io.vov.vitamio.widget.VideoView
    android:id="@+id/surface_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

[image]

Now i'm sure code work well.

Thanks hope this will help you .

Comment: In the beginning, I used the same code which you have suggested. But now the problem is in HTTP link. Any Suggestions for solving the HTTP link or RTMP?

Comment: i'm using rtmp link in this example

Comment: and i'm not getting how you are looking for http link ? if stored video you want to play then it work with http link but if you are using live streaming then only rtsp or rtmp link will work.

Comment: oh, I saw some code working with HTTP link. So I thought I could try it since RTMP code was not working

Comment: http streams only work if that are stored in server.You need to try with RTMP only

Comment: I tried your code with RTMP link. The app is crashing :( I am getting an exception linke this: `java.lang.NullPointerException: uriString`. I have inserted the RTMP link instead of `url play` in your code.

Comment: please debug it, surely something is missing in declaration

Comment: or please check you are getting url or not ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123596/discussion-between-saveen-and-joshua).

Comment: I checked out bro, still the app is crashing with the same null pointer exception in the line where the RTMP is present :(

Comment: surely something is missing, please debug everything line by line

Comment: I have added the code. Please view it and help me find the problem.

Comment: checked the code video view have some problem but i try to use **vitamio**. its working fine. I'm updating my answer pls check

Comment: I tried with **Vitamio**, Unfortunately, I am getting the same result (i.e) Audio is playing but video is blank. I have added the code and screenshot. plz check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123754/discussion-between-saveen-and-joshua).